# Column referencing after dplyr doesn't work

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is a reproducible example:

I will start by assigning the mtcars dataset to a variable called `temp`.

```
temp = mtcars
```

If we try to reference a column in this df, it works as expected. Results in a 'double'.

```
typeof(temp[,'wt'])
'double'
```

Now perform a simple `group_by` and `mutate` from the `dplyr`. Then `ungroup`.

```
temp = temp %>% group_by(gear) %>% mutate(var.wt = var(wt))
temp = temp %>% ungroup()
```

The resulting column reference is not a double anymore but a list.

```
typeof(temp[,'wt'])
'list'
```

If I try to compute the `mean` of the referenced column, it doesn't work and results in the following error.

```
mean(temp[,'wt'])
In mean.default(typeof(temp[, "wt"])) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

How do I perform the `mean` with column reference after the dplyr functions?

Comment: Some more background can be found here: [Advanced R - Data frames and tibbles](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#tibble)

Answer (score 2):

`tibble`s are strict about subsetting (whereas `data.frame`s are not).

If `df` is a `tibble` then indexing with

- `[` will always return a `list` (a `tibble` to be precise), and
- `[[` will always return a `vector`.

This is different to `data.frame`s where indexing a single column with default `drop = T` automatically converts a `list` to a `vector`.

In base R, compare your example with e.g.

```
# Implicit conversion to vector
mtcars[, "wt"]
```

and

```
# Simulating the "tibble way"
mtcars[, "wt", drop = FALSE]
```

The latter will return a similar error to the one you've experienced when you do `mean(mtcars[, "wt", drop = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 2):

The `dplyr` package is part of the `tidyverse` which is built around a modified version of the `data.frame` called a `tibble` which behaves slightly different from a normal data.frame.

```
class(temp)
[1] "data.frame"

temp2 = temp %>% group_by(gear) %>% mutate(var.wt = var(wt)) %>% ungroup()
class(temp2)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

One difference is that when you subset a single column of a tibble, the result remains a tibble, rather than being converted to a vector as with a data.frame:

```
temp[,'wt']
 [1] 2.620 2.875 2.320 3.215 3.440 3.460 3.570 3.190 3.150 3.440 3.440 4.070 3.730 3.780 5.250 5.424 5.345 2.200 1.615 1.835 2.465 3.520 3.435 3.840
[25] 3.845 1.935 2.140 1.513 3.170 2.770 3.570 2.780

temp2[,'wt']
# A tibble: 32 x 1
      wt
   <dbl>
 1  2.62
 2  2.88
 3  2.32
 4  3.22
 5  3.44
 6  3.46
 7  3.57
 8  3.19
 9  3.15
10  3.44
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Since `mean` expects to act on a vector, it returns an error when you use it with a `tibble`. You can either use `as.data.frame` to convert it back to a data.frame:

```
temp3 <- as.data.frame(temp2)
class(temp3)
[1] "data.frame"

mean(temp3[,'wt'])
[1] 3.21725
```

Or subset with `$` or double brackets `[[` which both return vectors:

```
temp2$wt
 [1] 2.620 2.875 2.320 3.215 3.440 3.460 3.570 3.190 3.150 3.440 3.440 4.070 3.730 3.780 5.250 5.424 5.345 2.200 1.615 1.835 2.465 3.520 3.435 3.840
[25] 3.845 1.935 2.140 1.513 3.170 2.770 3.570 2.780

mean(temp2$wt)
[1] 3.21725

mean(temp2[['wt']])
[1] 3.21725
```

Answer (score 1):

There are other people that have pointed out that your class has changed and this is why you are getting a problem. But there are reasons why some classes (including tibble in dplyr) do things the way they do. And understanding will help you build more robust code in the future.

Let's look at some objects and their classes.

Start with the mtcars dataset. It's a data.frame.

```
temp = mtcars
class(temp)
# [1] "data.frame"
```

When you subset it using the default square brackets you get a numeric vector.

```
temp2 <- temp[,'wt']
class(temp2)
# [1] "numeric"
```

When you do some work on the mtcars data using dplyr you get a tibble (aka tbl) back out.

```
temp3 <- group_by(gear) %>% mutate(var.wt = var(wt)) %>% ungroup()
class(temp3)
# [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

When you try to subset this tibble you get another tibble!!!

```
class(temp3[,"wt"])
# [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

But WHY!? Well, the answer is that tibbles assume that you always want a tibble back. Dataframes assume that you want a dataframe back unless there is only one column selected. If you are programming through an arbritrary number of columns this is a good thing because your code will always perform the same.

There are two ways to get a tibble to return a column. First is to use the `$` notation.

```
class(temp3$wt)
# [1] "numeric"
```

The other option is to use the `drop = TRUE` option. This will change the default behavior of the tibble and make it drop everything but the vector.

```
class(temp3[,"wt",drop = TRUE])
# [1] "numeric"
```

Comment: Someone else pointed out that you can also use the double brackets `[[]]`